# Splitting Rebased Branches

Tags: git, split, git-branch

I just rebased 2 of my branches:

**Development ---> Master**

[Here is my current structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUinC.png)

But then when I tried to make another branch (ui) it doesn't split. I want to split it up so I can have a clear representation of the flow of my commits. What can I do to split them up on separate nodes.

Comment: Now all the three branches point to the same commit(the same node), so they share the same history. You don't have to "split them up" and it's uncessary. When you checkout `ui` and make new commits, it will move on with its own new history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one branch is directly ahead of the other (they says "the other is contained within the first") most tools will draw both branches as one line:

```
-*--*--*--*--*
       |     |
      dev   master
```

To "split" them you need to add non-related (not yet merged) commits to both branches:

```
        dev
         *
        /
-*--*--*
        \
         * master
```